# How do I count the number of specific digits in an integer

Tags: python, math

I want to make a program so that it counts the total number of 6's between two integers.

For example the total number of 6's that appear from 1 to 99 is 20.

How would I make this for larger numbers on python?

Would appreciate help!

Comment: How would you do it for less larger numbers?

Comment: There is exactly one six in the low order digit for every 10 consecutive integers. And one six in the 10s position for every 100 consecutive integers. And so on. Of course that six in the 10s place persists for 10 consecutive integers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really a math question, not a programming question. Please try https://math.stackexchange.com to understand the formula, then come back if and when you have a specific question about implementing a math formula in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it with `sum` and `count`:

```
>>> sum(str(n).count("6") for n in range(1, 100))
20
>>> sum(str(n).count("6") for n in range(1, 100000))
50000
>>> sum(str(n).count("6") for n in range(1, 10000000))
7000000
```

For much larger numbers you might need to come up with some clever algorithmic trick rather than actually doing it as a linear operation.  I can roughly envision something with recursion and memoization that involves getting the answer for a smaller subset of the digits, multiplying it by 10 for each of the 10 digits that can be combined with it, and then adding 1 for the 6 that occurs in one of those possibilities, but if you don't actually need to do this for numbers that greatly exceed a million I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that might work for you, I don't know how large of numbers you're looking to parse through...

```
str(list(range(1, 1000000))).count('6')
```